# Error gen[0] is undefined when trying to access an object in an array with React js

Tags: reactjs, pokeapi

I'm currently having a problem when trying to access an object inside an array pulled from PokeApi
Here's my fetch API which works fine :

```
const [gen, setGen] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        axios
        .get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/generation")
        .then((res) => {
            return res.data.results;
        })
        .then((results) => {
            return Promise.all(results.map((res) => axios.get(res.url)));
        })
        .then((results) => {
            setLoading(false);
            setGen(results.map((res) => res.data));
        });
    }, []);

    console.log(gen);
```

And here's a part of what I'm trying to display :

```
<h2 className='gen_container_inner_title'>{gen[0].name}</h2>
<h3 className='gen_container_inner_region'>{gen[0].main_region.name}</h3>
```

I also have another fetch from another API URL with the same method

The problem is that sometimes it works and shows the info needed but sometimes it says

```
gen[0] is undefined
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and why it's not working every time

Edit : the code nt working is inside this :

```
{loading ? (
  <BarWave width="40px" height="20px" color="#cc0000" />
  ) : (
```

Comment: ```{!loading && <h2 className='gen_container_inner_title'>{gen[0].name}</h2>}
      {!loading && <h3 className='gen_container_inner_region'>{gen[0].main_region.name}</h3>}```
Try to add a condition before those JSX

Comment: You are trying to render `gen[0]` before they are initialize value from `axios` response. One of the many ways you can prevent rendering the gen[0] before initialize is add a condition if `axios` is loading then not render, after loading is false when `axios` is done with fetching the render those JSX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `gen` array might not have items when the first time it renders.
You can use [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)(?.) along with [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)(??) to get rid of the errors.

```
<h2 className='gen_container_inner_title'>{gen?.[0]?.name ?? ""}</h2>
<h3 className='gen_container_inner_region'>{gen?.[0]?.main_region?.name ?? ""}</h3>
```

Comment: @Tixarer, check this out !!

Comment: Thx a lot it's working. Do you know why the array doesn't have the items the first time it renders them ?

Comment: Because the default value for useState is given as an empty array. That's what considered for the first time rendering.

Comment: Ok thx for the explanation :)